# my url does not return nil but empty string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, url

below is the code where based on url I need to get the image.
But url is not nil instead it is double quotes "" or empty string.
Hence how do I handle check for double quotes in swift.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] () -> Void in

    if let url = NSURL(string: arr[indexPath.row].imgl){

             if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {

                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     cell.img.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)!
                }
              }
          }
   }
```

if url is "" then it should go to else part.

Comment: Can you show us your json?

Comment: @pkc456 - url is string stored in the array - arr ( arr[indexPath.row].imgl )

Comment: Share the dictionary which your array holds

Comment: your problem is there in arr, please give the arr

Comment: Unrelated but the `[weak self]` is pointless. `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles. And don't use `NSURL` and `NSData` in Swift, use native `URL` and `Data`. And **never** load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`, not even in a background thread.

Comment: @pkc456 - arr[indexPath.row].imgl returns ""

Answer (score 3):

Convert this:

```
NSURL(string: arr[indexPath.row].imgl)
```

to this:

```
URL(string: arr[indexPath.row].imgl)
```

.

> how do I handle check for double quotes in swift?

```
if myString.isEmpty {
   print("its empty. Means it is just two double quotes without anything between")
}
```